# Is the stdout file descriptor not properly opened if you don't print anything?

Tags: c, io, dup2

In the following code, both printfs go to terminal, despite the IO redirection using dup2:

```
int main() {
  int out_fd = open("test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, DEF_MODE);
  int saved_stdout = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup2(out_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
  close(out_fd);

  printf("Should be in test.txt\n");

  dup2(saved_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO);
  close(saved_stdout);

  printf("Back in the terminal\n");
}
```

However, when I insert an extra print before the first dup2, "Should be in test.txt" successfully shows up in test.txt:

```
int main() {
  puts("Weird");
  int out_fd = open("test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, DEF_MODE);
  int saved_stdout = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup2(out_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
  close(out_fd);

  printf("Should be in test.txt\n");

  dup2(saved_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO);
  close(saved_stdout);

  printf("Back in the terminal\n");
}
```

Is there a reason that the IO redirection failed when I didn't print anything to stdout beforehand?

EDIT: Solved! Fflushing the first printf right after it's printed ensures it gets printed to test.txt.

```
int main() {
  int out_fd = open("test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, DEF_MODE);
  int saved_stdout = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup2(out_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
  close(out_fd);

  printf("Should be in test.txt\n");
  fflush(stdout);


  dup2(saved_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO);
  close(saved_stdout);

  printf("Back in the terminal\n");
}
```

Comment: You are suffering from buffering. Use `fflush`

Comment: @ikegami Where should I fflush, and what should I fflush? Do I fflush(stdout) instead of my puts("Weird")?